# Databricks / Spark error - dependency update?

Tags: azure, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm quite new to `databricks`. There's an error I keep getting (almost at random - doesn't seem to be an issue with my code as such) that can only be resolved by restarting the cluster. The error is:

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure
>
> ...
>
> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to fetch
>   spark://10.100.52.23:37487/files/packages.tar during dependency update

Has anyone seen this before? Any chance you know why this is happening, please?

My code is written in R and I have the package `xgboost` installed on the cluster. This is the only library that isn't included in the defaults, I think.

Comment: Which databricks Runtime Version are you using?

Comment: Did you find any solutions to this problem ? Even we are having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

raised ticket with Microsoft and their engineering team has repsonded as in given below.

The spark_apply() function bundles user code (closure) in a file named package.tar. When there are multiple sparklyr jobs, some executors may get assigned a task when they do not have access to the bundle file.

This need to be addressed in upstream sparklyr to use a unique name for the bundle file here. we filed an issue with Sparklyr community that  be tracked here. https://github.com/sparklyr/sparklyr/issues/2244.

So it appears to be a known issue, for now our team will be fixing this bug but that will take some time.